# Error loading "main.ts" at http://localhost:8083/Angular2/main.ts.js

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am new to angular 2 . I am trying to build a basic angular 2 project in which my main.ts.js file is not getting loaded.

location of main.ts- WebContent/main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app : 'app', // 'dist',
        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: { main: './boot.js', defaultExtension: 'ts' },
        rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
});
})(this);
```

Comment: does your `main.ts` belongs to `/app/WebContent` folder?

Comment: you doing it completely wrong. You **should not** call a single file TS or JS. Please read more on how Angular working. In easy case - start with Angular CLI - there's **a lot** of tutorials on how to start developing with Angular.

Comment: @Jasper I am following this tutorial onlyhttp://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2017/06/angular-2-nested-components.html

Comment: @PankajParkar app is inside webcontent .

Comment: well, then you have to do couple of things 1. change `app : 'app', // 'dist'` to `'app': 'WebContent'`. 2. Then change `app` options of `packages` to `app: { defaultExtension: 'js' },`